# JSON enviado de PHP y leerlo en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, json

He implementado una función en javaScript que me toma el valor indicado y luego lo consulta con php en la base de datos pero al momento de regresar con un JSON de php y leerlo en javaScript no puedo sacar los datos

Código JavaScript:

```
function capturar(){
    var celular = document.getElementById("celular").value;
    $.post("php/listarInformes.php", { celular: celular}, function(data){
        var datos = data;
        alert(datos.nombres);
    });
}
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();

include "conexion.php";
include "funciones.php";


if(isset($_POST["documento"]) || isset($_POST['celular'])){

    $datos='';



    if(!empty($_POST['celular'])){

        //INFORMES
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM informes WHERE celular='".$_POST['celular']."';";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if(empty($fila['codigo'])){

            //CLIENTE
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE celular='".$_POST['celular']."';";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if(empty($fila['codigo'])){



            }else{

                //CLIENTE
                $datos=array(
                    "documento"=>"".$fila['dni']."",
                    "nombres"=>"".$fila['nombres']."",
                    "apellidos"=>"".$fila['apellidos']."",
                    "fecha de nacimiento"=>"".$fila['fechaNacimiento'].""
                );




            }
        }else{

            //INFORMES
            $datos=array(
                "documento"=>"".$fila['dni']."",
                "nombres"=>"".$fila['nombres']."",
                "apellidos"=>"".$fila['apellidos']."",
                "fecha de nacimiento"=>"".$fila['fechaNacimiento'].""
            );

        }

    }



    echo json_encode($datos, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}




?>
```

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionar tu problema Eduardo?

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que el error se presenta porque no se le está indicanto a PHP el tipo de dato que debe de retornar. Yo probaría con lo siguiente:

```
<?PHP

$json['dato1']=$dato1;
$json['dato2']=$dato2;


// Aquí se define en la cabecera de la respuesta el tipo de dato a retornar.
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el servidor envía el JSON el navegador lo recibe como un string, por eso no se pueden leer sus propiedades, pero podemos usar JSON.parse para que se evalúe el string y nos devuelva el objeto correspondiente al JSON recibido.

Pruébalo reemplazando la linea que dice

```
var datos = data;
```

por esta:

```
var datos = JSON.parse(data);
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: por favor explica por que ese cambio ayudaría? que diferencia hace el uso de eval()

Comment: ¡Por favor no usen eval, es una puerta super fácil para la inyección de código.

Comment: Tenés razón, ya lo corregí. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que el output de PHP es correcto lo que necesitas es que JS "digiera" ese JSON hacia un `Object Literal`:

```
function capturar(){
    let celular = document.getElementById("celular").value,
        json;
    $.post("php/listarInformes.php", { celular: celular}, function(data){
        //var datos = data; ¡no es necesario crear una variable que está creada ya!
        console.log(data); //esto muestra la respuesta de PHP en crudo, directo en la consola
        json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json.personas);
    });
}
```

Presiona F12 si usas Chrome para abrir la consola, ahí puedes ver el resultado. Si el problema está en PHP por favor comparte un poco más del output que genera tu script.